# Create a removable React component without having to re-create remove function

Tags: reactjs, components

I am looking to create a "delete-able" / removable React component that I can use in multiple different places.

From researching, I can see it is kind of an anti-pattern to create a component that deletes itself and the correct way to do things is for the parent to manipulate the child components rather than child components modifying themselves.

This has led me to write code somewhat along the following lines:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [ XXX ]
        };
    }
    
    removeFunc = (index) => {
        const test = this.state.data.filter((_,i) => i !== index);
        this.setState({data: test});
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map((el,i) =>
                <ChildComponent removeFunc={() => this.removeFunc(i)}/>
            )
            }
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

---

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        removeFunc: props.removeFunc
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.state.removeFunc}>Delete Me</button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

The issue I have with this is that I have to keep re-writing the `removeFunc` function in every parent component.

I am VERY new to React, so I'm just curious if there is there a better / different way to do this or is this the correct way?

Comment: The `removeFunc` handler in the parent component is common. It's anti-pattern to store passed props into local state in the child though, especially since it's just a callback, attach the handler function directly to the button's `onClick` handler, i.e. `onClick={this.props.removeFunc}`. If you find yourself writing the same ***exact*** code/logic over and over, look for the common design patterns to handle this, i.e. Higher Order Components, custom React hooks, utility functions, etc...

Comment: Sorry, @DrewReese, I'm not sure what you mean by attaching the handler to the button's `onClick` handler since that is only in the child and the callback is in the parent. Can you explain?